# Iterate file name with counter

Tags: python, counter

I'm splitting a file based on a string, and would like to have the output file names be numbered.

This is what I have so far:

```
outputfile = open("output.seq")   
outputfileContent = outputfile.read()
outputfileList = outputfileContent.split(">")
for count, line in enumerate(f):
    for items in outputfileList:
        seqInfoFile = open('%f.dat', 'w')
    seqInfoFile.write(str(items))
```

I'm not sure where to define f.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How does `output.seq` look like? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: what is `f` in that code

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I haven't misunderstood you, where you have it.

```
outputfile = open("output.seq")   
outputfileContent = outputfile.read()
outputfileList = outputfileContent.split(">")

for count, content in enumerate(outputfileList, 1):
    with open("output_%s.dat" % count, "w") as output:
        output.write(content)
```

Comment: I was about to post a similar thing. Simple one.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that if you want to associate every item in the output file list with a file titled as its index, you should do something like this:

```
for i in range(len(outputfileList)):
    seqInfoFile = open(str(i) + '.dat', 'w')
    seqInfoFile.write(str(outputfileList[i]))
```

It's not quite as elegant as an iterator, but the other option is to determine the number by making a call to outputfileList.index(items) each time.

Answer (score 0):

Open `output.seq`, write its first line (splitted at `>`) into the file `1.dat`, the second one to `2.dat` and so on:

```
with open("output.seq") as fi:
    for count, line in enumerate(fi, 1):
        with open('{0}.dat'.format(count), 'w') as fo:
            fo.writelines(line.split('>'))
```

Comment: He sounds like he wants to output the split text, not each line.

Comment: @Julian - then let's split it…